what are the .openssh.asc text files and how to generate/sign/verify one?
eg.: https://www.freebsd.org/security/advisories/FreeBSD-SA-24:08.openssh.asc
The Question: how can i make an openssh.asc file from my plain TXT file? And how can i verify it? Does it always needs to be max 78 character long per line?

.asc is used for various PGP files (messages, keys). The extension comes from the fact that they're "ASCII-armored" (Base64), while .pgp or .gpg are raw binary formatted ones. It is basically the PGP equivalent of .pem files.
The specific format your file has is a PGP "clear-signed" message. Most PGP software can generate such files, e.g.:
gpg --clearsign hello.txt

This requires you to have your own PGP key with which to sign; see --gen-key.
Other tools are Sequoia's sq and sop. Most GUIs such as Kleopatra should also be able to produce clear-signed messages.
This format was meant to be used in email messages (before MIME), so although it isn't strictly limited to 78 characters per line, this is the traditional formatting for ASCII email and therefore also for clear-signed PGP messages.
To verify it, give it to any PGP software, such as GnuPG:
gpg --verify FreeBSD-SA-24:08.openssh.asc

This usually requires you to have the signer's (FreeBSD) key imported, and the most important step of verifying the key's fingerprint depends on you.
